# Getting unexpected output while handling double values in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have to perform certain calculation on a value which is stored as a varchar,First I am converting the value into a double and then trying to multiply the double value with 0

Eg
Query: Select cast('-12345.67' as Double)*0;

Output: -0 (Negative zero)

Expected Output: 0 (zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IEE754 standard for floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) as used by most computers defines signed zero format: +0 and -0.
The notation "−0" may be used informally to denote a negative number that has been rounded to zero.

**Example in C:**

```
double d= -0.001;
printf("double is %f\n", (double)d * 0);
```

Output:

```
double is -0.000000
```

To avoid this, cast to DECIMAL

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select cast(-1.2345 as decimal) * 0;
+------------------------------+
| cast(-1.2345 as decimal) * 0 |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
```